# Django Syncdb error

Tags: django

Running Django Syncdb tries to create two tables with the same name "auth_group" and it quits with the error at the bottom.

```
python manage.py syncdb 

Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
..
Creating table auth_group
```

Returns this error

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'auth_group' already exists")
```

Comment: Can you include `INSTALLED_APPS` definition from the `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have duplicate `'django.contrib.auth'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: There is only one reference of 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED APPS. Tried commenting it out, none of contrib.auth tables are created

Comment: Check your `models.py`, it might contain the django.contrib.auth models (happens if you use `inspectdb` after the database is generated), you should only have YOUR modules there, none of the third-party ones